# Map List<String> with Mapstruct from Java POJO to Protobuf (proto3)

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, mapstruct, proto3, protobuf-java

I'm trying to map some POJOs from Java to Protobuf (proto3). Some of them contain Lists. While mapping lists with POJOs (for example List) is no problem, I'm getting a UnsupportedOperationException.

Example with `List<Product>` (this works corrctly):

```
ProductProtobuf.Builder map(Product product);

@Mapping(target = "productsList", source = "products")
ResponseProtobuf.Builder map(Response response);
```

Example with `List<String>` (this doesn't work):

```
@Mapping(target = "usersList", source = "users")
ResponseProtobuf.Builder map(Response response);
```

Additionally, I have some Mapper for builder:

```
public ResponseProtobuf.Builder responseBuilder() {
    return ResponseProtobuf.newBuilder();
}

public ProductProtobuf build(ProductProtobuf.Builder builder) {
    return builder.build();
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that MapStruct will use `getProductsList().addAll()`. In order to avoid this you should use `CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED` `collectionMappingStrategy`. Have a look at the [`UserMapper`](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/master/mapstruct-protobuf3/usage/src/main/java/org/mapstruct/example/mapper/UserMapper.java) from the [mapstruct-protobuf3](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-protobuf3) in the mapstruct examples repo.

In a nutshell you need to add:

```
@Mapper(collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED,
    nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)
```

to your mapper.

One information regarding your builder, in case you are using 1.3.0.Beta1 you won't need it as there is out of the box support for that in MapStruct now.

NB: There was a [bug](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1338) in MapStruct that was not working correctly with `ProtocolStringList`. This bug has been fixed in 1.3.0.Beta1. If you try with this version it should work (in case your `productList` is a `String`)

Comment: I forgot to write that I already used:

`@Mapper(collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED,
    nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)`

The problem occures ONLY for List<String> because MapStruct would create an object of type ProtocolStringList (instead of String<List>), which is an interface and therefore can't be used.

Comment: Can you update your issue with this information, please. I will update the answer with the fix

Comment: How about from Protobuf to Java POJO?

Comment: @0xTomato for that, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72244381/3667003

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same issue and solve it like this:

```
    @AfterMapping
    void afterMapping(@MappingTarget ResponseProtobuf.Builder target, Response response) {
       target.addAllProducts(response.getProducts());
    }
```