# MapStruct map Protobuf (proto3) to Java POJO

Tags: java, mapping, protocol-buffers, mapstruct, grpc-java

I'm trying to map from Protobuf to POJO. Here's the POJO:

```
public class CreateNodesAllDataDto {
    private List<UpsertNodeDto> tables;

    private List<UpsertColumnDto> columns;
}
```

where `upsertNodeDto` is the following:

```
public class UpsertNodeDto {
    @NotNull
    private String workspaceId;

    @NotNull
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;
}
```

And here's the Protobuf:

```
message UpsertNodeAllDataInput {
  repeated UpsertTableInput tables = 1;
  repeated UpsertColumnInput columns = 2;
}

message UpsertTableInput {
  string workspace_id = 1;
  string id = 2;
  string name = 3;
}
```

You get the idea.

The problem right now is that MapStruct does not map the `repeated` fields in Protobuf because the getters for these fields in the generated Java file is name *xxx-list*. For example, the way to get `tables` from `UpsertNodeAllDataInput` is `input.getTablesList()` rather than `input.getTables()`, and apparently MapStruct does not recognize that.

First of all there's definitely no Protobuf generation issue, because [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/), a similar-purpose package, works in conversion `UpsertNodeAllDataInput` and `CreateNodesAllDataDto`. It is also not an issue of MapStruct installation since it works for POJO to POJO mapping for me. The problem is only one described above.

I've been looking around for a while and have only found answers on mapping POJO to Protobuf. Things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416941/map-liststring-with-mapstruct-from-java-pojo-to-protobuf-proto3) don't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

The following is an excerpt from an example of how to map the `repeated` fields in Protobuf with MapStruct to POJO (and also using Null check):

```
import org.mapstruct.CollectionMappingStrategy;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.MappingConstants;
import org.mapstruct.NullValueCheckStrategy;
import org.mapstruct.ValueMapping;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper(collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED,
        nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)
public interface UserMapper {

    UserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);


    @Mapping(source = "permissions", target = "permissionsList")
    @Mapping(source = "mainDepartments", target = "mainDepartmentsList")
    @Mapping(source = "departments", target = "departmentsList")
    UserDTO map(User user);

    @Mapping(source = "permissionsList", target = "permissions")
    @Mapping(source = "mainDepartmentsList", target = "mainDepartments")
    @Mapping(source = "departmentsList", target = "departments")
    User map(UserDTO userDTO);

    @ValueMapping(source = "UNRECOGNIZED", target = MappingConstants.NULL)
    Permission map(PermissionDTO permissionDTO);

    PermissionDTO map(Permission perm);


    Department map(DepartmentDTO departmentDTO);
    DepartmentDTO map(Department department);
}
```

For the whole example, see:
[Source](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/master/mapstruct-protobuf3/usage/src/main/java/org/mapstruct/example/mapper/UserMapper.java)
[Discussion_related_to_the_issue,_and_the_source_referencing_comment](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/743#issuecomment-410801945)